Why Docker Failed to remove container-related anonymous volume
Here are my instructions for running the container:
docker run -p 5432:5432 --name=db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -d --mount type=volume,src=postgres_data,target=/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
docker volume ls

Here is the result:
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     postgres_data

And I verify that the container is running properly 
And excute the
docker rm --help 

command then prompts me that this cmmand can remove the anonymous volume associated with the container:
Options:
  -f, --force     Force the removal of a running container (uses SIGKILL)
  -l, --link      Remove the specified link
  -v, --volumes   Remove anonymous volumes associated with the container

Then I do this:
docker stop db
docker rm -v db
docker ps -a

Here is the result:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

Although the container has been removed, the volume is still there and I don't understand why:
docker volume ls

DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     postgres_data

how can i remove a container also removes the volume associated with the container

Does this help? https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/volume/rm/

thank you,i know i can use "docker volume rm" to remove the volume,But what i want is  remove the container  the volume associated with the container at the same time

When you remove a container with the docker rm -v command, it will remove the container and any anonymous volumes associated with it. However, named volumes(whichpostgres_data in your case) are not removed by default, even if you use the -v flag.
Why postgres_data is still there:
The volume postgres_data is a named volume, not an anonymous volume. Named volumes are designed to persist data even when a container is removed, and they need to be manually deleted.
Simply, you can use this command "docker volume rm postgres_data"

No,you misunderstand my intentions.I want use "docker rm -v db" to remove the volume in one line of command while  removing the container like it says in the hints

Oh,Now i understand,That's why I failed.Thank you so much,you save my day
